# Running multiple instances of puppeteer results in slower loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, automation, puppeteer

I am using worker threads + puppeteer to achieve some how of multithreading so i can open multiple browsers without affecting the speed of it but look like that didnt worked is it a threads problem ? or it's just the nature of puppeteer ?

```
const {Worker,isMainThread,workerData,} = require("worker_threads");
if (isMainThread) {   
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    new Worker(__filename)
    });
  }
  //) This re-loads the current file inside a Worker instance.
} else {
  Main();
}
```

Main() here is the function that holds the basic puppeteer options the main function.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

main = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
}
```

**Edit** : i added a the puppeteer function
1- the problem would appear whenever do more than 1 task of automation for example 1 task takes 4 sec t finish the job 2 would take 6 and the more i add the more time it ould takes
2- i have core i 7 7700hq which is  8 Threads/Core

Comment: I even used cluster but same problem

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++)` only loops once so it's pointless. Please show a [mcve] with the simplest Puppeteer code needed to repro the problem and describe your relevant system specs. What didn't work, specifically? How many instances are you trying to run and why? Using multithreading or multiprocessing doesn't guarantee free lunch (perfect parallelization) on all workloads. Regardless of whether you use threads, Puppeteer runs the browser (headlessly or not) as a subprocess. If you're running more processes than you have CPUs, there will be contention. Memory matters too -- it's finite.

Comment: the first code block raises questions on the `)` brackets. Possibly the for loop has one too many, and another one is commented out. The entire block is not nicely formatted at all, I will edit it a little